# C# - Performance of reusing object with string properties vs creating new instance

Tags: c#, string, performance

Suppose I have class A that contains 3 string properties. New instances of A are being created several times needlessly throughout the application. All class A does is use these 3 strings to perform a LINQ query like:

Where(string1 == this.string1).Where(string2 == this.string2).Where(string3 == this.string3)

Instead of creating an instance every single time the object is needed, I'm thinking about modifying the classes that use this type to store one instance of the object and then modify the string properties before using it each time. Is this the right way to optimize the class? Basically, I'm trying to avoid the overhead of creating the instance and allocating the memory for the strings every time.

Is there a faster way to perform the above LINQ query instead?

Comment: You would need to code up both options and **measure** the performance.

Comment: A class "containing" three strings is tiny because the strings aren't "contained" in it per se. You need to understand how classes are stored, how strings are stored, you need to understand string interning, you need to understand garbage collection and the cost of GC0, 1 and 2. Then maybe you'll be ready to consider optimizing this class.

Comment: Creating the different strings are most likely more expensive that creating your holding instance. That said, unless the strings are giant this sounds like premature optimization. Don't try to guess performance problems. Measure then optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. But unless there're plenty of those objects, the difference in performance will be negligible.

Comment: How do you know it would be negligible?

Comment: How do you know how long it takes to `new` up an instance of `A`? And how performant the OP's object pooling would be?

Comment: @Enigmativity, OP probably means the average class A which has, say, 5-10 fields, since he's cleared that up. For this, what I've written is true.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but you don't know what the OP's actual implementations are with both his class `A` and what pooling code he's going to use. Until we know that and actually measure the difference then we can't be sure of the results. I suspect you're right, but we just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If "several times" is on the order of a few thousand then I wouldn't worry about the performance of creating the objects.  Only if you are creating so many that the application is having to frequently perform a garbage collection to cleanup the unused objects, which for an object with 3 properties would need to be on the order of millions unless your strings are extremely large.

You are more likely to create bugs by trying to reuse an object, since you run the risk of forgetting to clean object state between reuses.

Trying to reuse the object will likely mean moving it to a higher level scope than necessary.  I.e. changing a local reference to a property, or similar.

Keep your code simple, rather than implement premature optimizations, such that when you do get into a situation where optimization is really important, then you can more easily implement optimizations.  If you over optimize everything you can imagine, then you will end up with an over complicated code base.

**Update:**

> I'm thinking about modifying the classes that use this type to store
>   one instance of the object and then modify the string properties
>   before using it each time. Is this the right way to optimize the
>   class?

You're not saving much in the realm of memory allocation.  Since you are assigning new strings each time, most of the allocation is in the creation of the strings, not in the creation of the object.

The outer object consists of little more than 3 pointers.

Whether you reuse the same object repeatedly, or not, the majority of memory allocation is the creation of strings each time.

If you are going to put effort into optimization, your efforts should be focused where they will be most beneficial.  Efforts devoted to optimization should begin with profiling to determine where your slow points are.  This means optimizing those things that have been measured to be problem areas.

Comment: Is there another way to optimize this that would not complicate the code too much?

Comment: @Andrew without knowing your application structure, I would guess the answer is no.  The problem with premature optimization is that you are optimizing something that is already very efficient. Between the compiler and the garbage collector, there are alot of very advanced algorithms involved to optimize code and memory. It is unlikely anything you do will improve performance significantly, unless you are in a very specific scenario where you've identified a noticeable performance problem.

Comment: It's a bit like trying to polish a mirror with sandpaper. A mirror is already pretty smooth, and it's unlikely you can smooth it more with crude sandpaper, and likely make it worse.

Comment: I read about string interning and it sounds like a lot of these strings get cached in a string intern pool anyway. Basically, what class A does is use those 3 strings to perform a LINQ query such as "Where.(String1==this.String1) && (String2 == this.String2) && (String3 == this.String3). I don't have the exact syntax right. I wonder if I can optimize the LINQ query instead (uses Entity Framework)?

Comment: Now we're talking about optimizing a LINQ query instead of optimizing memory access.  I would suggest creating a new question and include more code than just the snippet so it is clearer what you are doing with this data and what the complete query looks like.